# state.cartItems is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux-form

I am new to react. I am not able to figure out the solution. On adding a product to the cart I am not able to see it in the cart scree. Please suggest any changes. The error I am getting is : state.cartItems is not iterable (cartReducers.js:26).

CART ACTION:

```
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`)
    console.log(data);
    dispatch({
      type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
      payload: {
        product: data._id,
        name: data.name,
        image: data.image,
        price: data.price,
        countInStock: data.countInStock,
        qty,
      },
    })
    console.log(data);
    console.log(getState().cart.cartItems)
    localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems))
  }
```

REDUCER:

```
  export const cartReducer = (
    state = { cartItems: []},
    action
  ) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case CART_ADD_ITEM:
        const item = action.payload
        
        const existItem = state.cartItems?.find((x) => x.product === item.product)
  
        if (existItem) {
          return {
            ...state.cartItems,
            cartItems: state.cartItems?.map((x) =>
              x.product === existItem.product ? item : x
            ),
          }
        } else {
          return {
            ...state.cartItems,
            cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item],
          }
        }
      case CART_REMOVE_ITEM:
        return {
          ...state.cartItems,
          cartItems: state.cartItems.filter((x) => x.product !== action.payload),
        }
      default:
        return state
    }
  }
```

Below is the cart component. I want to access all the cart items and calculate total quantity and price.
CART COMPONENT:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Row, Col, ListGroup, Image, Form, Button, Card } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import { addToCart, removeFromCart } from '../actions/cartActions'

const CartScreen = ({ match, location, history }) => {
  const productId = match.params.id

  const qty = location.search ? Number(location.search.split('=')[1]) : 1

  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart)
  const { cartItems } = cart

  useEffect(() => {
    if (productId) {
      dispatch(addToCart(productId, qty))
    }
  }, [dispatch, productId, qty])

  const removeFromCartHandler = (id) => {
    dispatch(removeFromCart(id))
  }


  return (
    <Row>
      <Col md={8}>
        <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
        {cartItems?.length === 0 ? (
          <Message>
            Your cart is empty <Link to='/'>Go Back</Link>
          </Message>
        ) : (
          <ListGroup variant='flush'>
            {cartItems?.map((item) => (
              <ListGroup.Item key={item.product}>
                <Row>
                  <Col md={2}>
                    <Image src={item.image} alt={item.name} fluid rounded />
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={3}>
                    <Link to={`/product/${item.product}`}>{item.name}</Link>
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={2}>${item.price}</Col>
                  <Col md={2}>
                    <Form.Control
                      as='select'
                      value={item.qty}
                      onChange={(e) =>
                        dispatch(
                          addToCart(item.product, Number(e.target.value))
                        )
                      }
                    >
                      {[...Array(item.countInStock).keys()]?.map((x) => (
                        <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>
                          {x + 1}
                        </option>
                      ))}
                    </Form.Control>
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={2}>
                    <Button
                      type='button'
                      variant='light'
                      onClick={() => removeFromCartHandler(item.product)}
                    >
                      <i className='fas fa-trash'></i>
                    </Button>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
            ))}
          </ListGroup>
        )}
      </Col>
      <Col md={4}>
        <Card>
          <ListGroup variant='flush'>
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <h2>
                Subtotal ({cartItems?.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.qty, 0)})
                items
              </h2>
              Rs.
              {cartItems?.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.qty * item.price, 0)
                .toFixed(2)}
            </ListGroup.Item>
          </ListGroup>
        </Card>
      </Col>
    </Row>
  )
}

export default CartScreen
```

Comment: can you show how you build the store and you redcuer ? and where you are calling this dispatch

Comment: It looks like you're duplicating the cartItems. Why is there both `...state.cartItems` *and* `cartItems: ...`? From reading the code however, `state.cartItems` should always be an array at least, so that doesn't explain your error. I'd put a console.log in the `CART_REMOVE_ITEM` case and inspect the state, something about the structure is off.